# How to send the gmail authentication token to the server node js api?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, mobile, oauth

I'm creating a mobile app which uses the

- google login (OAuth) for Authentication
- it has a backend exposed as Node JS api

Now, I'm trying to create an *Authenticated API* based upon the *google login*. 
So, only the logged in user (through gmail), will be able to call the *api*.

- Now, I'm not sure how do I get the *JWT* token from gmail, pass it to the api as *bearer token*?
- Also, how would my server verify the *JWT* token without knowing the *secret* password? Would my server in turn has to call the *gmail* server for token verification?

I'm not sure if this is a standard approach? I searched over the internet, couldn't find this kind of scenario. Any help is much appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following resources, which guide through Implementing Server Side Authorization:

[Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)

[Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use server side authentication.
You can use npm module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-auth